# How to stop the execution of async function using a state in React

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, state

I have an async function running, I want to stop the execution of that function using a state. The problem is that the isRunning variable doesn't get updated inside the function.

Here is my simplified code:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const runAsyncTask = async isRunning => {
    while (isRunning) {
        await delay(1000);
        console.log("running...");
    }
}

const App = () => {
    const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(true);
    
    runAsyncTask(isRunning)
    
    return (
        <button
            onClick={() => {
                setIsRunning(false);
            }}>
            STOP
        </button>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Could someone explain to me how should I be approaching what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: You're creating another new infinite loop every time you call it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is a closure, and the value of `isRunning` inside the closure is always `true`. When you call the function again on render, the original closure is not affected, and you create a new loop that starts an ends immediately, since the value of `isRunning` is `false`.

Run the loop inside a `useEffect` block, so renders won't create new loops, and pass the value of `isRunning` into the closure using a reference. The reference is an object that points to a value (`current`) that can be controlled from the outside.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const runAsyncTask = async isRunningRef => {
  while (isRunningRef.current) {
    await delay(1000);
    console.log("running...");
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(true);
  
  const isRunningRef = useRef(isRunning);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    isRunningRef.current = isRunning;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    runAsyncTask(isRunningRef)
  }, []);

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setIsRunning(false);
      }}>
      STOP
    </button>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<App />);
</script>
```

In this case, you can also use the ref directly, since refs are mutable, and don't require render:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const runAsyncTask = async isRunningRef => {
  while (isRunningRef.current) {
    await delay(1000);
    console.log("running...");
  }
}

const App = () => {  
  const isRunningRef = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    runAsyncTask(isRunningRef)
  }, []);

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        isRunningRef.current = false;
      }}>
      STOP
    </button>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<App />);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. If I don't want to re-render something I can just use the reference directly without using a state, right?

Comment: Welcome. See 2nd example.